# Problem with recursion for backtracking, gets stuck

Tags: recursion, backtracking

I have written code that duplicates chess Knight at every move 2 times this happens until the board is filled, I go over all the possible position combinations, if one fails it backtracks and tries another one. Problem is it seems to get quickly stuck and repeats the same 6 or more positions all over again, I have spent a lot of time on debugging it but I can't figure out how to fix it. Could anyone help? Some ideas what could be the problem causing it? Thanks in advance.

````py
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(str(square) for square in row))


def is_valid_move(x, y, board_size):
    return 0 <= x < board_size and 0 <= y < board_size


def knight_moves(board, position):
    possible_moves = []
    moves = [(-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1)]

    for move in moves:
        new_x = position[0] + move[0]
        new_y = position[1] + move[1]

        if is_valid_move(new_x, new_y, len(board)) and board[new_x][new_y] == 'E':
            possible_moves.append((new_x, new_y))
    
    return possible_moves


def convert_to_chess_row(row_number, board_length):
    return board_length - row_number


def is_filled(board):
    for row in board:
        for e in row:
            if e == 'E':
                return False
    return True


def backtrack(board, current_pos, moves):

    if is_filled(board):
        return True

    possible_moves = knight_moves(board, current_pos)

    if len(possible_moves) >= 2:

        board[current_pos[0]][current_pos[1]] = 'F'

        for pos_first in possible_moves:
            for pos_second in possible_moves:

                if pos_first == pos_second:
                    continue

                board[pos_first[0]][pos_first[1]] = 'K'
                board[pos_second[0]][pos_second[1]] = 'K'

                print(str(pos_first) + str(pos_second))
                print_board(board)
                print("\n\n")

                if backtrack(board, pos_first, moves):
                    return True

                if backtrack(board, pos_second, moves):
                    return True

                board[pos_first[0]][pos_first[1]] = 'E'
                board[pos_second[0]][pos_second[1]] = 'E'

        board[current_pos[0]][current_pos[1]] = 'E'
    return False


def play(board_size: int, pos: str) -> Optional[list[str]]:
    board = [['E' for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]

    position = pos[-2:]
    pos_tuple = (convert_to_chess_row(int(position[1]), len(board)), alphabet.index(position[0]))


    if is_valid_move(pos_tuple[0], pos_tuple[1], len(board)) is False:
        return None

    moves = []

    board[pos_tuple[0]][pos_tuple[1]] = 'K'

    backtrack(board, pos_tuple, moves)

    if is_filled(board):
        return moves
    else:
        return None

 

print(play(6, "qKc3"))```


Tried going over all possible moves on chessboard, the result is that it gets stuck somewhere.
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77469406/problem-with-recursion-for-backtracking-gets-stuck

Comment: @NVRM, why post a link to this same page?

Comment: *"repeats the same 6 or more positions all over again,"*: exactly which positions are repeated? Please list them. Secondly, do you have the *literal* description of the code challenge? Can you quote it?

Comment: What problem are you solving here?

Comment: I let it run for quite some time and it turns out it's not stuck but just takes too long, but I need it under 2 minutes, the code challenge is about annexing the whole board with knights, you have one Knight at the start and you have to duplicate it into 2 new knights and you can do the same with them, only once tho

Comment: I don't understand 'only once though'. Also your code is not really duplicating the nights. It adds 2 knights in each recursive calll. So you go from 1 to 3 to 5....

Comment: Yes, that's what is the duplicating supposed to mean, the only once means you can only do it once for knight, so when you go from 1 to 3, you can use the second one and third one but not the first one anymore